# java mail - getting message by message ID

Tags: java, android, email, imap

I'm developing Android mail client. I need to build a "conversation" structure for every email message. I use the

```
IMAPMessage.getInReplyTo()
```

method that returns the Message ID of message  which the message is a reply to. Unfortunatelly there seems to be no easy way to obtain message from

```
IMAPFolder
```

using its message ID. It is only possible to get the message by its UID. Is there an easy way to get the IMAP message by its Message ID?

Comment: myabe this will help? 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/Gmail-Help-POP-and-IMAP-en/F9TQJAO493w

Comment: No, this is not a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `IMAPFolder`'s `search` method like this:

```java
SearchTerm searchTerm = new MessageIDTerm(messageId);
Message[] messages = imapFolder.search(searchTerm);
```

See the docs for the `IMAPFolder`'s `search` method here:
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-

and for the `MessageIDTerm` class here:
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/MessageIDTerm.html

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no straight forward solution... May be what you can try is to maintain an internal structure with `body structures` of all the mail ids and then perform a one on one Message-ID check and obtain the UID of mail. Anyways you would be doing it, in order to show the Maillist. Add a new logic to map the message-ids as well.